# Are sannyasins/sadhvis allowed to give advice on marriage and kids?

Tags: women, sannyasa

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadhvi_Rithambara):

"She got her diksha from Swami Paramanand, at the age of sixteen and having become his disciple, followed him to his ashram in Haridwar and then, in his tours across India, while being primarily trained in oratory."

Considering she's never been married, can she give such advice to Hindu men/women on marriage and kids? Do Hindu texts allow it?

[image]